# Get third coordinate in the straight line when two coordinates are given

Tags: vector-spaces

Are there exist some kind of way of getting point (ex: A ) which is on straight line, third coordinate when we know the remaining two? For example we know x and y coordinates of point A which lies somewhere in line. How do we get the remaining z axis?

Comment: Are you asking: Given a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and two coordinates of a point $A$ on the line, can we find the third coordinate of $A$?

Comment: Yep, exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the line. For example, if the line is

$$\{(0,0,t)\in\mathbb{R}^3\ |t\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

then there are infinitely many points with first two coordinates zero.

---

On the other hand given a point $A=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ on a line whose direction is not $(0,0,1)$ we can determine the unique value of $x_3$ once $x_1$ and $x_2$ are known.

Consider the line through $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ with direction $q=(q_1,q_2,q_3)$:

$$\{p+tq\in\mathbb{R}^3\ | \ t\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

where $q$ is not parallel to $(0,0,1)$, i.e. at least one of $q_1$ and $q_2$ is nonzero. Since $A$ is on the line

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(p_1+tq_1,p_2+tq_2,p_3+tq_3)$$

for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $q_1$ and $q_2$ are not both zero, knowing  $x_1$ and $x_2$ allows us to solve for $t$ (given $q_i$ is nonzero,  $t=\frac{x_i-p_i}{q_i}$) and therefore calculate $x_3=p_3+tq_3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I love how you put your answer in nice shape! After watching this clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PyPp4QvQY3Q and reading through your answer, everything now makes perfect sense.